# Writing files to windows machine from Broker (Unix)

Tags: java, ibm-mq, messagebroker

I have a requirement to `create/append` file on windows machine from `WebSphere Message Broker Toolkit` v 7.0 (Unix). Unix user does not have permissions to access the windows machine. I wanted to write a `Java` code which can create or append to a file with other credentials which has access to windows machine (not `FTP`, it's a shared drive in the same network but a different group).

I found some solutions which the client don't want to use whatever constraints.

1. Creating a `NFS` mount point and write to that mount point location.
2. Use `SAMBA` framework.

Can anyone suggest something other than this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where will the message flow be deployed? On the same Windows server as the file or a different machine? Do you want remote unix users to be able to send a message to this flow and the file to be created/updated with the remote user's credentials or the server's credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Run a WebSphere MQ Managed File Transfer agent on the Windows host.  Then the broker can simply send files to the agent which will write them to the local filesystem on the Windows host.  This capability is built into modern versions of MQ.